# SQL query exception issue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Am trying to insert a record into my database using a function that consists of 11 arguments as input. The function is as follows:

```
public int check_in_visitor(int visitor_id,String date_in, String date_out,
    String time_in, int check_in, int check_out, String employer,
    String vehicle_number, int manual_entrychk, String time_out)
```

The corresponding query for it:

```
String query = "insert into visitor values('"+visitor_id +"','" +
    date_in + "','" + date_out + "','" + time_in + "'," + check_in +
    ",'" + check_out + "'," + employer + ",'" + vehicle_number + "'," +
    manual_entrychk + ",'" + time_out + "')
```

its always giving errors like expression incorrect! Please help me solve the issue

Comment: what is the datatype of `manual_entrychk` in DB?

Comment: have you tried print out `query` and check its sql syntax?

Comment: int. however visitor_id is bigint. I hope int in visual studio is equivalent to bigint in sql management studio??

Answer (score 3):

Use SqlParameter..
That way you would avoid sql injection attack,enclosing data with `'` or `"` & other issues..

```
String query = "insert into visitor values(@visitor_id,@date_in,@date_out,@time_in,@check_in,@check_out,@employer,@vehicle_number, @manual_entrychk,@time_out)";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("visitor_id", visitor_id));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("date_in", date_in));
....
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: @user3081555 `visitor_id` would be replaced at @visitor_id in query...That way you don't need worry about enclosing it within `'` or `"` Have a look at [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) tutorial

Comment: after defining parameters this is what i should do for execute insertion command? command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = query;
            int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: @user3081555 You need to have all the parameters in your query prefixed with `@`..After that for each such parameter you need to do `commad.Parameters.Add("parametername",parameterValue);`

Comment: and after that the above lines that i mentioned?? command = connection.CreateCommand(); command.CommandText = query; int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to close the Query String with double quotes.

```
String query = "insert into visitor values('"+visitor_id +"','" + date_in + "','" + date_out + "','" + time_in + "'," + check_in + ",'" + check_out + "'," + employer + ",'" + vehicle_number + "'," + manual_entrychk + ",'" + time_out + "')";
```

Note1 : all `VARCHAR` feilds should be enclosed in `single` quotes properly.

Note 2: all `INT` feilds should not be enclosed with `single` quotes.

Note 3: your query is open to SQL injection attaks. please use parameterised queries.

untill unless you provide the feild types its defficult to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use string.format. Like `string query = string.Format("insert into visitor values ('{0}','{1}'...",vistor_id ...);` This syntax is a lot easier to troubleshoot and avoids the string concatenations. You should also consider not using data that's not fully trusted in your query (like anirudh mentioned in his reply), if that's an option at all.

Answer (score 0):

if query below doesnt help you, please tell what is the error returned?

```
string query = "insert into visitor values ("+visitor_id+ ","+ date_in +","+date_out
        +","+time_in+","+check_in+","+check_out+","+employer+","+vehicle_number+","
        +manual_entrychk+","+time_out+")";
```